# Phonegap Build external link system browser from Iframe

Tags: cordova, hyperlink, build, external

Basically, a previous developer had created a Phonegap Build app that utilizes iframes to pull content. I'm trying to get links within that iframe to open up in the system IOS browser. I have cordova installed properly, as well as calling the inappbrowser plugin etc. I am using the windows.open '_system' code to pull the link. It works fine in a browser but when I try from the app, the link just opens inside the app. This makes me close the app just to get back because there is no 'back' or 'close' button.

Is it because its an iframe? I've been looking around everywhere and still nothing seems to be working.